# How can i use async function in vue template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

This is my example:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="id of SomethingChanging">
    {{ getSomethingAsync(id) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods:{
   async getSomethingAsync(id){
      try {
        const result = await getSomethingAPI(id)
        return result.payload
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

All we know, ​async function will return a promising object ...

How can I fix it so that the page will return the truly data?

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough details. Is it Vue 2 or 3? Vue 3 has suspense. What is the real case? `id in 5` looks like bogus code. It's unclear why you couldn't fetch data on mount.

Comment: Thank you all. But i still dont know why couldnt vue2 template use async function directly？Could Vue 3 use async function directly in template and get result directly?

Comment: Because this isn't how Vue works. Promise object is a promise of a result, not a result itself, supporting them in templates would require the framework to work very differently than it works now. No, in Vue 3 you couldn't do this too but could use `async setup(...)` and the value would be available at the time when a template is rendered

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to call methods inside template to render something, because this could give some issues like infinite rendering, instead of that you can define a data property that you can fill it inside the created hook like :

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="item in result">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
 data() {
    return {
      result: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getSomethingAsync(id) {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + id)

        return result.data
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.result = await Promise.all([...Array(5)].map((_, i) => {
      return this.getSomethingAsync(i + 1)
    }))
  }
</script>
```

**Example**

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      result: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getSomethingAsync(id) {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + id)

        return result.data
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.result = await Promise.all([...Array(5)].map((_, i) => {
      return this.getSomethingAsync(i + 1)
    }))
  }
})
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-axios@2.1.4/dist/vue-axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in result">
        {{ item.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```