# How to queue method call in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I call method with queue?
Let say I have a method, this method will call the API and it needs to handle only 3 call at a time. When more than 3 calls from some component. It needs to wait until any of the call finish and run the next

This is just illustration, I don't loop API call, the real project is call API by user action

```
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  doSomething(i)
}

doSomething(param){
//call api
}
```

It should call doSomething 0 - 9, but I want to call api for the first 3, and the other will wait until any of the call is finished

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68198288/8172857

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thank you for commenting, I don't think it implements queue, it's just a basic call

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions for the implementation.

A sample implementation.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  doSomething(i)
}

async function doSomething(param) {
//call api
  if ( param < 3 ) {
    const x = callApi();
    console.log(x);
  } else {
    const x = await callApi();
    console.log(x);
  }
}

async function callApi() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('success')
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it will do the first three, and the other will run one by one. What I really need is, the method can call up to 3 at a time not only for the first three but all. So let's say the first three calls is finished almost at the same time, and then it should do the next three call immediatelly